# Wordpress Plugins Error

Tags: plugins, errors

I get this message when I go to add a new Plugin. Do you know a way to solve this?

An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.[image]

Comment: It's worth checking your server's error log in case there's any more information there. (or your PHP error log if you have a separate log, or wp-content/debug.log if you've enabled that.)

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to several different reasons. The quickest answer is to ensure your server is running PHP 7.4+ and the cURL extension is enabled.

If the problem persists, suggest reading through the support forums to see if you can find information relative to your situation.

Comment: curl - yes, although I'd be surprised if WordPress lets you get that far without it. Why would the PHP version matter though?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if the plugin wp.org SVN repository is up and running:

You should be able to confirm using this url, with name of plugin at the end:

https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/smartlink-dinamic-urls/

If there's a tag / branch folder with the plugin inside then wp.org repo is Ok.

You can then check if server configuration is fine. Go to tools >> site health >> server  and check all files have write permission,

Additionally, check that server options has recommended values.
| option | value |
|:----- |:-|
| upload_max_filesize | 16 MB or greater |
| memory_limit | 128 MB or greater |
| max_execution_time | 60 or greater |
| max_input_vars | The minimum value is 4000 but the recommended is 6000. |